# change LinearLayout to left to right

Tags: android, android-layout

In this layout I want to change the position of the "ایمیل" to right...
I used layout gravity and gravity without any success, anyone know how do it with the fewest changes ?

```
  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_small"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <com.pt.chfnt.view.widget.OpenSansRegularTextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/lblSignupHeaderWidth"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_padding_xxtiny"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="ایمیل:" />


            <com.pt.chfnt.view.widget.OpenSansRegularTextView
            android:id="@+id/lblEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xnormal"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_padding_small"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_padding_small"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_padding_xxnormal"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_padding_small"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_register"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: set textview width to fill the row and then set gravity

Comment: Use Relative layout instead of LinearLayout and keep that TextView in separate LinearLayout and you can change the position of it then.

Comment: Confused: 'change LinearLayout to left to right' and 'change the position of the "ایمیل" to right' are two different things.
.
The LinearLayout is also horizontal which can mean additional things
.
Its a wonder why there's now three different opinions.

Comment: Do you want it to the right in a rtl environment?

Answer (score 0):

Onemore option to try

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="First"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**EDIT**

Another Option not sure if it will suffice

I assume you've enabled rtl support in your manifest file like described here:
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

adding android:supportsRtl="true" to your application element

Then you can try this -> which has the whole layout reversed not only the text (this is reversing it android:layoutDirection="rtl")

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl">
    <TextView
        android:text="First"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: In frame layout ? I was just giving another option if you don't have any specific requirement to use LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Use relative layout if you want to use layout_gravity.
Otherwise just place the desired text below the email one.

Comment: But then he'll need to figure out the distance between elements, otherwise they will be near one another i think

Comment: He can then use layout_weight (in case he's using linear layout).

Comment: True, I thought about it also but than It's not with wrapped content again (but you're right)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution's I found...

```
 android:id="@+id/lblEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xnormal"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_padding_small"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_padding_small"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_padding_xxnormal"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_padding_small"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_register"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_weight="0.90" />

            android:layout_width="@dimen/lblSignupHeaderWidth"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_padding_xxtiny"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="ایمیل:"
            android:layout_weight="0.10" />
```